# Dividing 2 rows in a column that is corresponding to two other columns and their relation(Python)

Tags: python, pandas, division

I have a dataframe shown below, what I want is for each element in "nom_1" column to carry out a division of it's corresponding target_1 to target_0. So for `"Circle"` the `"id"` for `"target_1"` is 9168 and `"id"` for `"target_0"` is 28152. I need the division of 9168/28152. I could do this manually but I need it to be automatized because there will be many more dataframes as this with different unique values.

I need to create a dictionary that looks like this as a result:

```
{'Circle': 0.3705589911482963, 'Polygon': 0.34775978284076003, 'Square': 0.5312055617001106, 'Star': 0.19850208121615415, 'Trapezoid': 1.5383163853653423}
```

**Note**: These numbers do not represent the actual outcome just the format I'd like

Here's my code so far:

```
    nom_1  target     id
0      Circle       0  28152
1      Circle       1   9168
2     Polygon       0  24741
3     Polygon       1  11402
4      Square       0  32787
5      Square       1  16810
6        Star       0  31645
7        Star       1  14259
8   Trapezoid       0  71833
9   Trapezoid       1  29348
10   Triangle       0  19078
11   Triangle       1  10777

nom_1_dat = train.groupby(["nom_1","target"]).count()[["id"]].reset_index()

print(nom_1_dat)

nom_1_dict = {}
i_list = []
for i,element in enumerate(nom_1_dat["nom_1"]):
    i_list.append(i)
for i,element in enumerate(nom_1_dat["nom_1"]):
    if (i+1) < max(i_list): 
        nom_1_dict[element] = (nom_1_dat["id"][i+1])/(nom_1_dat["id"][i])

print(nom_1_dict)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['Circle', 'Circle', 'Polygon', 'Polygon'], [0, 1, 0, 1], [28152, 9168, 24741, 11402]], ['nom_1', 'target', 'id']).T
     nom_1 target     id
0   Circle      0  28152
1   Circle      1   9168
2  Polygon      0  24741
3  Polygon      1  11402
```

Try this code, using [groupby.agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df_res = df.groupby('nom_1').agg({'id': lambda row_id: row_id[1]/row_id[0]})
```

or equivalentelly, using [groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df_res = df.groupby('nom_1').apply(lambda row: (row[row.target==1]['id'].iloc[0]/row[row.target==0]['id'].iloc[0]))
```

In both cases gives:

```
               id
nom_1            
Circle   0.325661
Polygon  0.460854
```

If you want to convert the result to dictionary:

```
dict_res = df_res.to_dict()['id']
# output: {'Circle': 0.3256606990622336, 'Polygon': 0.46085445212400467}
```

Comment: I'm getting a KeyError with the first code. I don't know if I can post code in the comments but let me try.   df = train.groupby(["nom_1", "target"]).count()[["id"]].reset_index()
print(df)

nom_1_m = df.groupby('nom_1').agg({'id': lambda row_id: row_id[1]/row_id[0]})

dict_res = nom_1_m.to_dict()['id']

Comment: The error in your code is in the first line when you create `df`, but I can't help you because I don't know the format of your `train` data. The following lines of code I posted are correct. Try updating your question and adding train values. However if you try the input of my answer, you get the result you were looking for

Comment: Yes, @Massifox I added my solution as an answer. Your solution version #2 worked for low cardinality columns but I got a KeyError for high cardinality ones with over 2000 unique values. I'm not really sure if this is due to high cardinality, I tried debugging to see the problem behind the error however I could not figure it out. Thank you so much for helping me out !

Comment: I don't think it's a cardinality problem, you probably have some missing / dirty value in the train dataset, which at some point makes you access a field that doesn't exist / null by generating 'KeyError'. Without seeing the dataset I can't help you :-) The important thing is that you managed to solve! If you think my answer may have helped you, accept it and voteup for it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict={}
values = df['nom_1'].unique() # find the norm_1 unique_values
for value in values:       # iterate over values
    df_t=df[df['nom_1']==value] # get the value from dataframe
    dict[value]=int(df_t[df_t['target']==1]['id'])/int(df_t[df_t['target']==0]['id'])  # divide the target_1/target_0
print(dict)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried answers given. When I tried them on columns with high cardinality I got a KeyError. I modified my previous code and got the desired outcome:

```
nom_1_dat = train.groupby(["nom_1","target"]).count()[["id"]].reset_index()
print(nom_1_dat)
nom_1_dict = {}
i_list = []
for i,element in enumerate(nom_1_dat["nom_1"]):
    i_list.append(i)
for i,element in enumerate(nom_1_dat["nom_1"]):
    if element not in nom_1_dict.keys():
        nom_1_dict[element] = (nom_1_dat["id"][i+1])/(nom_1_dat["id"][i])
print(nom_1_dict)
```

---

```
#output:
{'Circle': 0.3256606990622336, 'Polygon': 0.46085445212400467, 'Square': 
0.5127032055387806, 'Star': 0.45059251066519196, 'Trapezoid': 0.40855874041178847, 
'Triangle': 0.5648914980605934}
```